# Java JPA doesn´t create new table (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

i´m currently learning Spring Boot, and trying to set up JPA with a MySQL database. Everything looks fine, the project starts correctly, no visible errors, but...no table is created on my db. I´ve checked everywhere and everything seems fine, i have no clue what´s causing that behaviour...
I´ll leave the relevant parts of the code:
ProjectApplication.java:

```
package com.first.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

My Student class:

```
package com.first.project.student;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(
          strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
  )
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
  private Integer age;

  public Student() {
  }
  public Student(Long studentId, String studentName, String studentEmail, LocalDate studentDoB, Integer studentAge) {
    this.id = studentId;
    this.name = studentName;
    this.email = studentEmail;
    this.dateOfBirth = studentDoB;
    this.age = studentAge;
  }

  public Student(String studentName, String studentEmail, LocalDate studentDoB, Integer studentAge) {
    this.name = studentName;
    this.email = studentEmail;
    this.dateOfBirth = studentDoB;
    this.age = studentAge;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
  }

  public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }

  public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
  }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/(my database)
spring.datasource.username=(my username)
spring.datasource.password=(my password)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

The dependencies from my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Inside the main package i have ProjectAplication, and a subpackage with the Student class inside.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` ? because `create-drop:` drop the schema at the end of the session

Comment: witch version of spring-boot are you using ?

Comment: some version of mysql needs you to create the DB first where the app will not create it and after that you will find your table

Comment: Most probably you have a version conflict. You can't mix javax-persistence with spring boot 3+ JPA (aka Jakarta). The best way to generate a clean pom.xml is to use https://start.spring.io/ and add only the dependencies needed like data-jpa and mysql.

Comment: @Mar-Z         that was the issue, I switched to Jakarta and it works now, thanks!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/(my database)
spring.datasource.username=(my username)
spring.datasource.password=(my password)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Here, spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop means that the application creates tables when it starts and drops them when it exits. To view the tables after the application ends, you can change it to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update. The modified configuration would look like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/(my database)
spring.datasource.username=(my username)
spring.datasource.password=(my password)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

With this change, the application retains the tables after it exits, allowing you to view them later.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. i´ve tried all options on spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto, but none worked. It´s not that it creates and then deletes the table, it just doesn´t create it. The start log shows it´s connected to the database, but there´s no query in sight, and no table in my local database

Answer (score 0):

you use create-drop so table is created when you start application and dropped when you stop and if your application is runnig and still doesn't show table so try to do this : check database name is match to spring database , and try to do refresh in mysqlworkbench

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

try this in pom file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your sql is not connected make sure you add the mysql connector jar file
Or can simply add this command in your pom.xml file

`<groupId>mysql</groupId>  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> <version>8.0.23</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->  </dependency>`

Sometimes it is cause you don't have relevant port, check your port in mysql client command line
by this code
mysql -h your_host -P your_port -u your_username -p -e "SELECT @@port;"

I hope this helps!